# Javascript Libraries update: backbone.localStorage, Backbone, Underscore, jquery, jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, local-storage, underscore.js

I'm having some issues working on a HTML5 Mobile App.

Well the issue that I'm learning from a tutorial and all the javascript libraries are old so I am having some errors. The first problem I had was when modifying the source code of backbone.localStorage.js file, just 2 lines inside a method and then more issues keep on comming

If I use the old libraries as in the videos my code works perfectly, but if not, if I change any of them some features will stop working.

So here are some details:

libraries:

jQuery.js: In the course they use version 1.5.1 and I'm using version 2.0.3

jQuery Mobile: in the course they use version 1.0a3 and I'm using version 1.3.2

underscore.js:

backbone.js:

backbone.localStorage.js:

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Taking Notes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home page -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Local Notes</h1>
            <a href="#new" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right">New</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#new" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">New note</a>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#all">All Notes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nearest">Nearest Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- New Note Form -->
    <div id="new" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>New Note</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input id="title" name="title" value="">
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea id="body" name="body" value=""></textarea>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="locate">Tag With Location</label>
                    <select name="locate" id="locate" data-role="slider">
                            <option value="no">No</option>
                            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button data-icon="check" data-theme="b">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of Notes -->
    <div id="all" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
            <h1>All Notes</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="all_notes">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of Note detail pages -->
    <div id="note-detail-list">
    </div>


    <script type="text/template" id="note-list-item-template">
        <a href="#note_<%= note.id %>" ><%= note.get('title') %></a>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="note-detail-template">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1><%= note.get('title') %></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <%= note.get('body') %>

            <% if(note.isGeoTagged()){ %>
            <h3>Location</h3>
            [<%= note.get('latitude') %>, <%= note.get('longitude') %>]

            <%  } /* End if */ %>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Application.js

```
var NotesApp = (function(){
  var App = {
    stores: {},
    views: {},
    collections: {}
  }

  // Initialize localStorage Data Store
  App.stores.notes = new Store('notes');


  // Note Model
  var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Use localStorage datastore
    localStorage: App.stores.notes,

    initialize: function(){
      if(!this.get('title')){
        this.set({title: "Note @ " + Date() })
      };

      if(!this.get('body')){
        this.set({body: "No Content"})
      };
    },

    // Returns true if the Note is tagged with location data
    isGeoTagged: function () {
      return this.get('latitude') && this.get('longitude');
    }

  });


  var NoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // This collection is composed of Note objects
    model: Note,

    // Set the localStorage datastore
    localStorage: App.stores.notes,

    initialize: function(){
      var collection = this;

      // When localStorage updates, fetch data from the store
      this.localStorage.bind('update', function(){
        collection.fetch();
      })
    }

  });


  // Views
  var NewFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "submit form":  "createNote"
    },

    createNote: function(e){
      var attrs = this.getAttributes(),
          note = new Note();


      function create(){
        // Save
        note.set(attrs);
        note.save();

        //Close
        $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        this.reset();

      }


      if (attrs.locate == 'yes' && 'geolocation' in navigator) {
        // Do geolocate
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          // Handle Our Geolocation Results
          if(position && position.coords){
            attrs.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            attrs.longitude = position.coords.longitude
          }
          create();

        })
      } else{
        create();
      }



      // Stop browser from actually submitting the form (or following the link)
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stop jQuery Mobile from doing its form magic. We got this.
      e.stopPropagation();


    },

    getAttributes: function(){
      return {
        title: this.$('form [name="title"]').val(),
        body: this.$('form [name="body"]').val(),
        locate: this.$('form [name="locate"]').val()
      }
    },

    reset: function(){
      // Normal form.reset() would be ideal, but current causes
      // jQuery Mobile switches to fall out of sync
      this.$('input, textarea').val('');
    }

  });


  // Represents a listview page displaying a collection of Notes
  // Each item is represented by a NoteListItemView
  var NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');

      this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
      this.collection.bind('refresh', this.addAll);

      this.collection.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(note){
      var view = new NoteListItemView({model: note});
      $(this.el).append(view.render().el);

      if('mobile' in $){
        $(this.el).listview().listview('refresh');
      }
    },

    addAll: function(){
      $(this.el).empty();
      this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    }


  });

  var NoteListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'LI',
    template: _.template($('#note-list-item-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render')

      this.model.bind('change', this.render)
    },

    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template({ note: this.model }))
      return this;
    }

  })

  /* Container fore NoteDetailView
   *
   * Responsible for generating each NoteDetailView 
   */
  var NoteDetailList = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Render NoteDetailView[s] into this element
    el: $('#note-detail-list'),


    initialize: function(){
      // Make sure all functions execute with the correct 'this'
      _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render');


      this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
      this.collection.bind('refresh', this.addAll);

      this.collection.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(note){
      var view = new NoteDetailView({model: note});
      $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
      if($.mobile)
        $.mobile.initializePage();
    },

    addAll: function(){
      $(this.el).empty();
      this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    }
  });


  /**
  * Show Page
  */
  var NoteDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // View based on a DIV tag
    tagName: "DIV",


    // Use a template to interpret vakues
    template: _.template($('#note-detail-template').html()),


    initialize: function(){
      // Make sure render is always called with this = this view
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');

      // Updated this div with jQuery Mobile data-role, and unique ID
      $(this.el).attr({
        'data-role': 'page',
        'id': "note_" + this.model.id
      });

      // Whenever the model changes, render this view
      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    // Render the view into this View's element
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).html(this.template({note: this.model}));
      return this;
    },

  });





  window.Note = Note;

  App.collections.all_notes = new NoteList(null, {
    comparator: function (note) {
      return (note.get('title') || "").toLowerCase();
    }
  });

  App.views.new_form = new NewFormView({
    el: $('#new')
  });

  App.views.list_alphabetical = new NoteListView({
    el: $('#all_notes'),
    collection: App.collections.all_notes
  });

  // Initialize View for collection of all Note Detail pages
  App.views.notes = new NoteDetailList({
    collection: App.collections.all_notes
  });









  return App;
})();
```

Please help. I've being trying to solve this for a very long time and can't find the solution.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: For 1.3.2 it's recommended to use jQuery 1.9

Comment: When changing to jQuery 1.9 I got an error "Unexpected token" on underscore.js:1206

Comment: @David Knipe when I use all new versions I got the "Unexpected token" on underscore.js:1206. When I use all old versions, it works perfectly.

Comment: "Unexpected token" sounds like syntax error. Syntax error in underscore is very unlikely, but conceivable if you have some obscure javascript engine. (What's line 1206 anyway?) But no, I'd say it's syntax error in one (or both) templates. I know of no easy way of debugging these. Experiment: what if you write `template: _.template('')` for both templates? Maybe the `.html` method behaves differently in jquery 2 for invalid HTML (NB: the templates aren't valid HTML). What does `console.log($('#note-detail-template').html())` produce? And `console.log($('#note-list-item-template').html())`?

Comment: I just change to an old library. Thanks btw.